# Checking if a date falls between two dates and returns a string to another column in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I need to create a spreadsheet that will take a project date in Column C and then assign it a specific Period (Column B) based on what dates the project falls on.

Ex. Period 1x1 (B2) is >= Period Start Date (A2) and < Period Start Date (A3). Any Project Date (Column C) to fall in between those dates would be assigned as 1x1 in column N.

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIA7H.png)

```
Sub Main()


    Dim ProjectDate As Date
    Dim PeriodDate As Date
    Dim Period As String
    

    ProjectDate = Range("C2")
   

    
    If ProjectDate >= Range("A2") And ProjectDate < Range("A3") Then
    Period = "1x1"
    ElseIf ProjectDate >= Range("A3") And ProjectDate < Range("A4") Then
    Period = "1x2"
    End If
    
    Range("D2") = Period
    
    End Sub
```

This is as far as I have gotten (only 2 periods, I'll add the rest once I figure out what the issue is) but when I run it, it does not fill anything in Column D.
I think this is because the If statement isn't considering the Range as Dates and therefore can't distinguish if the ProjectDate falls between that range. I am also unsure how to expand it to further rows for the output Period as currently it's only going to display it in D2

EDIT: Removed the format code but it still does not return any values for column D

```
ProjectDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")
```

Comment: format returns a string not a date.  Dates to Excel are doubles, formatting should not matter as long as they are true dates.  Remove the Format line.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a For Each Cell loop and was able to get it working

```
    Sub Main()

    
For Each Cell In Range("C2:C1000")
    If Cell.Value >= Range("A2") And Cell.Value < Range("A3") Then
    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B2")
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= Range("A3") And Cell.Value < Range("A4") Then
    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B3")
     ElseIf Cell.Value >= Range("A4") And Cell.Value < Range("A5") Then
    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B4")

    End If
    Next Cell
    
    
    End Sub
```